# Does improved invisibility end due to caster's unconsciousness?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, invisibility

During last session, our wizard casted swift fly (free action) on himself while fighting a bunch of boneclaws. He actually went for a vertical jump-fly and then cast [improved invisibility](http://dndtools.eu/spells/players-handbook-30--106/improved-invisibility--3791/) on himself. He then started falling (as swift fly's duration is only for a single round).

Boneclaws are intelligent, so I ruled out that a boneclaw is entitled to a spot check to understand that he is about to fall near it. (VS DC 20 for invisibility). The boneclaw understood that something was there and attacked him with miss chance. He actually hit the wizard and got him in -3 or so HP.

Is the wizard still invisible while he is unconcious? Will the party's cleric need to spot him in order to heal him? And if he spots him, will the heal have a miss chance like the attack?

Comment: As an aside, this is why a cleric should have the spell *[status](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/status.htm)* up at all times once a 2nd level spell slot isn't needed for other things.  :)

Comment: Note: [swift fly](http://dndtools.eu/spells/complete-adventurer--54/fly-swift--422/) is a swift action, not free

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*** Is the wizard still invisible while he is unconscious?**

**Yes**. For invisibility the spell ends when the duration expires or "the subject attacks any creature.". Improved invisibility removes this restriction so the spell will only end when the duration expires, or if it is dispelled.

*** Will the party's cleric need to spot him in order to heal him?**

**Yes**. The hapless Wizard is invisible, so the cleric will have to spot him, but see the next answer as well.

*** And if he spots him, will the heal have a miss chance like the attack?**

**Yes**. (Sort of)
If the wizard is unconscious they will be [helpless](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#helpless). 
You wouldn't normally roll to attack to cast Cure Light Wounds on a merely unconscious target, it's assumed you can poke them - similar to how you can automatically hit when applying a [coup-de-grace](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatModifiers.htm#coupdeGrace) The problem is knowing *where* they are when they are [invisible](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD%3aInvisibility).

> A creature can grope about to find an invisible creature. A character
>   can make a touch attack with his hands or a weapon into two adjacent
>   5-foot squares using a standard action. If an invisible target is in
>   the designated area, there is a 50% miss chance on the touch attack.
>   If successful, the groping character deals no damage but has
>   successfully pinpointed the invisible creature’s current location. (If
>   the invisible creature moves, its location, obviously, is once again
>   unknown.)

So the cleric will have to grope around to find the unconscious Wizard, once they've located them with this method they can then cure them.
The cleric might want to get help from the rest of the party to find them, or maybe that spreading pool of blood on the floor is a helpful clue if the GM is feeling generous.

Comment: *"maybe that spreading pool of blood on the floor..."* Like you said, it's the GM's call, but this brings up the question of how abstracted from the target of the spell does a component of the target have to be to cease to be under the spell. If the blood eventually becomes visible, this sets a precedent that components of the spell target cease to be under the effects of the spell if abstracted from the target.